# Should JavaVisitor.maybeRemoveImport also remove imports of outer class?

Tags: java, openrewrite

If you pass an inner class to `maybeRemoveImport` then imports of the outer class are not removed. Is this intended or could this be a helpful extension of the method?

An example: I have this code

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class TestController {

    public void respond() {
       System.out.println(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

If I apply the recipe `ReplaceConstantWithAnotherConstant` to replace `javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status.NOT_FOUND` with `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` then the import `import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;` is not removed as `maybeRemoveImport` is called with argument `javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status`.

Comment: That indeed sounds like a bug and your suggestion makes sense. I suggest you report a GitHub issue for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for another good suggestion; I've converted your question here into a feature request: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/3101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question this was a [bug in OpenRewrite](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/3101) which meanwhile [has been fixed](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/commit/e790702babbb23e9c102f329434848811e365228) and is available as part of the latest 7.40.0-SNAPSHOT builds (see [documentation for instructions](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/snapshot-instructions)).

With this fix the `ReplaceConstantWithAnotherConstant` recipe will remove the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` import in the example you gave.